# Timer using Swift only counts down for 20 seconds, not twenty minutes

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am creating a timer on my app in iOS which counts down from 20 minutes to 0 seconds, one second at a time. So far the timer works but only counts down for 20 seconds, not minutes. It also doesn't stop when it gets to zero. How can this be resolved?

```
import UIKit

class SkippingViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startWorkoutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseWorkoutButton: UIButton!

    var timer = Timer()
    var counter = 20.00
    var isRunning = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func startWorkoutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        if !isRunning {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: -0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(SkippingViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
            pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
            isRunning = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseWorkoutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false

        timer.invalidate()
        isRunning = false
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        counter -= 0.01
        timeLabel.text = String(format: "%.01f", counter)
    }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the timer to stop at 0? You have no code to stop the timer. Fix your format: use `"%.2f"`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of issues that I see with your code that prevent it from working the way you want.

First of all, if the `timeInterval` passed in the `scheduledTimer` method is negative, it will always lead to a timer being created that fires every 0.1 milliseconds (source: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer#)).

What you want is your `updateTimer` to be called every second, so just pass 1.0 to the `scheduledTimer` method, e.g.:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SkippingViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Furthermore, you want to invalidate this timer when 20 minutes have passed since starting the timer. So when setting up the timer you could keep track of the current time, and when that time + 20 minutes is more than the current time when called in `updateTimer`, you can invalidate the timer. With other words, instead of counting down from 20 minutes, we are counting from 0 til 20 minutes have passed!

Example code (didn't try compiling it, but should work, let me know if it doesn't):

```
import UIKit

class SkippingViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startWorkoutButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseWorkoutButton: UIButton!

    var timer = Timer()
    var countDownFromMinutes = 20
    var timerStartTime: Date?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timeLabel.text = "\(countDownFromMinutes):00"
        startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func startWorkoutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        if !timer.isValid {
            // run every second
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SkippingViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            timerStartTime = nil
            startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false
            pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pauseWorkoutButtonDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
        startWorkoutButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseWorkoutButton.isEnabled = false

        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        guard let startTime = timerStartTime else {
            // first firing
            timeLabel.text = "\(countDownFromMinutes):00"
            timerStartTime = Date()
            return
        }

        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        // this ordinarily never returns nil, return gracefully if so
        guard let endTime = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: countDownFromMinutes, to: startTime) else {
            return
        }

        let differenceMinuteSeconds = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .second], from: now, to: endTime)

        // 20 minutes have passed since start
        if now >= endTime {
            timeLabel.text = "00:00"
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", differenceMinuteSeconds.minute ?? 0, differenceMinuteSeconds.seconds ?? 0)
    }
}
```

Note that I also replaced the `isRunning` var you added with using `timer.isValid` as I believe it would achieve the same without introducing another variable.

Only thing that is probably left is regarding the text of label you are displaying. I am not sure what you actually want to display here. If you can add that in the comments I can suggest an approach for that.

Comment: The text of the label is 20:00 when the timer starts and 0:00 when it ends. This method seems good but it has two errors. It says nil cant be assigned to type date in the 'timerStartTime = nil" . And the other error is in the 'if let startTime = timerStartTime { " it says 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Date''.

Comment: @MiriamLucas I'll update my code to reflect those issues + make the label do what you want

Comment: @MiriamLucas I updated the code to update the label. Again, haven't actually compiled it so please report if it works

Comment: By the way, in general you don't have to calculate end time in every iteration. You don't have to store start time. It's enough to calculate end time once, store it and then just compare with current time.

Comment: @Sulthan yes that is is certainly true but wasn't aiming for optimal space complexity here ;)

Comment: This looks more promising I had to do a bit of unwrapping, I just added ! where Xcode told me to. The last issue before I compile is in the line 'if now >= endTime {' is gives the error 'Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Date' and 'Date?' Thanks for all the help btw :)

Comment: @MiriamLucas please see edited code, forgot that something returned an optional. There should not be any need to use '!" to unwrap anything at other places.

Comment: FWIW, if I were just showing minutes and seconds, I’d probably instantiate a single [`DateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter), set its `unitsStyle` to `.positional`, its `zeroFormattingBehavior` to `.pad`, and its `allowedUnits` to `[.minute, .second]` and every time the timer handler is called, just use [`string(from:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter/1415967-string). Then no calendrical calculations or string formatting would then be needed.

Comment: @edwardmp I have added your new code and the line timeLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", differenceMinutesHours.hour, differenceMinutesHours.minute) gives back 3 errors: Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Int'  *** Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'  ***  Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil' thanks for all the work you have done with this

Comment: Thanks for your continued work on this. At the moment it compiles without any errors! Unfortunately, the timer when started just goes from 20.00 to 19.59 and counts down in minutes not seconds. To note as suggested by the other commenty I write 20*60 in the count down var because with just 20 it did nothing at all.

Comment: @MiriamLucas sorry I used hour + minutes instead of minute + seconds as you requested. Please see updated answer. This will be my final attempt though to prevent this from becoming a slowchat.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve set your timer’s interval to fire every 0.01 seconds, i.e. 100 times per second. And you’re adjusting the `counter` by 0.01 each time. So that means that it will decrement the `counter` at a rate of 1 per second. So a `counter` of `20` will expire in 20 seconds, not 20 minutes. If you want 20 minutes using your counter mechanism, you’d use `20 * 60`.

---

A couple of other observations:

1. Timers are not guaranteed to fire at the requested interval. It’s safer to save the time to which you’re counting down (or the time you started) and calculate the time elapsed from that. Then you can update the label with a nice string representation of the time elapsed.
2. You’re firing your timer every hundredth of a second. But screens don’t generally update with that frequency. Besides, you’re just showing minutes and seconds, so updating more frequently than that offers no benefit.

   If I were, though, showing milliseconds, and wanted an optimal timer frequency, I’d use a [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) rather than a timer. And, in the spirit of point 1, above, if you are using “start”/“stop” date to calculate how much time has elapsed, rather than a counter, you don’t have to worry about what this refresh rate is, since we’re no longer decrementing a counter.